# Upgrade Tomcat 7 to 64 bit JVM

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I have Tomcat 7 installed on a 64 bit CentOS system (I installed Tomcat 7 by downloading the apache-tomcat-7.0.xx.tar.gz file from the Apache Tomcat downloads site under "Core" and simply unzipping that on my CentOS box, not as a Unix deamon as described in the Tomcat setup documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html).) Prior to installing Tomcat the 32 bit JVM was installed on the machine.

My question is this: I want to install and use the 64 bit JVM on this machine for Tomcat to use instead of the 32 bit JVM. Do I need to do anything other than set JAVA_HOME to point to the new JVM? Are there any other Tomcat considerations that I need to take into account relating to the change in JVMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to tweak some of the memory settings to increase `-Xmx` and/or `-XX:MaxPermSize` but apart from that it should Just Work (TM).